# Rails sum column only if boolean is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following call to sum a users points for challenges:

```
 @points = current_user.challenges.sum(:xp)
```

On the challenges model there is an accomplished boolean. I want to sum the points for only the challenges belonging to the user that have the accomplished boolean true. How do I do that exactly in this call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user.challenges` is a relation so you can add more `where` calls to filter the results and then `sum` that:

```
@points = current_user.challenges.where(accomplished: true).sum(:xp)
# --------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going about it backwards. Suming, but trying to add the where after the fact. Like summin, but only if accomplished = true.